# Loopback inserts object id values as sequence and not random - how can i change it?

Tags: loopbackjs

Loopback inserts object id values for my MongoDB as sequence and not random.
for security reason, how can i change it to be random by default for all my models?

Will it affect the DB performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the way the ID is generated in the description file of your model:
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Model-definition-JSON-file.html#properties

```
model.json:

{
  "name": "model",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "strict": true,
  "idInjection": false, // disable default id!
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "id": true,
      "required": true,
      "type": "string",
      "defaultFn": "uuid"   // "guid" / "uuid" / "uuidv4" / "now"
    },
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Comment: It works but only without "generated": true. Is that safe to remove that? i don't want to users will be able to specify ids by themselves and i understood that the "generated": true parameter i can avoid that.

What do you think?

Comment: @Omtechguy, it looks like this problem still exists:
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/3029